# Webworks for BB 10. Open BB Maps at specific coordinates

Tags: javascript, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I hope that there is a genius webworks developer out there that can help me. I am working on a webworks app for BB10, and at some point, I want to open blackberry maps at given coordinates.

I have gotten an example from the net and managed to do get into bb maps, pass it coordinates and get navigation working. which is more complicated, but finding decent documentation on this is a nightmare... :O. My navigation/direction function looks like this...

```
function directions() {
blackberry.invoke.invoke({
    action: "bb.action.OPEN",
    type: "application/vnd.rim.map.action-v1",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "view_mode": "nav",
        "center": { "latitude": sessionStorage.lat, "longitude": sessionStorage.lon, "heading": 180, "zoom": 4 }, "nav_start": {
            "properties": {
                "name": "My Location",
                "description": "My Location",
                "address": "South Africa"
            },
            "latitude": sessionStorage.lat,
            "longitude": sessionStorage.lon
        },
        "nav_end": {
            "properties": {
                "name": stores[selectedStore].Name,
                "description": "No description Available",
                "address": "South Africa"
            },
            "latitude": stores[selectedStore].Latitude,
            "longitude": stores[selectedStore].Longitude
        },
        "nav_options": {
            "nav_mode": "fastest",
            "avoid_highways": false,
            "avoid_tolls": false,
            "transport_mode": "car"
        }
    })
});
```

}

This works great... Now I searched on the net and for opening the map on a set op coordinates, I saw this...

```
 function showmap() {

var args = new blackberry.invoke.MapsArguments(sessionStorage.lat, sessionStorage.lon);
blackberry.invoke.invoke(blackberry.invoke.APP_MAPS, args);
```

}

Now according to them you also need to add the following to your config file inside the widget tag.

```
<feature id="blackberry.invoke" />
<feature id="blackberry.invoke.MapsArguments" />
<license href="http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"></license>
```

This causes my app to crash... Just a plain crash and fail...

I am so stuck with this issue, I could really use some help. If you guys have any ideas or suggestions, I am open to them :)

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this out, and I believe the issue is your 'blackberry.invoke.mapargs....' in the config.xml. That's definitely not supposed to be there. Just the blackberry.invoke is all you should need.

I then ran the following code without problem

```
    blackberry.invoke.invoke({
    action: "bb.action.OPEN",
    type: "application/vnd.rim.map.action-v1",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "view_mode": "nav",
        "center": {
            "latitude": 43.46426,
            "longitude": -80.52041,
            "heading": 180,
            "zoom": 4
        },
        "nav_start": {
            "properties": {
                "name": "Display Name",
                "description": "Description",
                "address": "Waterloo, Ontario"
            },
            "latitude": 43.46426,
            "longitude": -80.52041
        },
        "nav_end": {
            "properties": {
                "name": "Display Name",
                "description": "Description",
                "address": "Ottawa, Ontario"
            },
            "latitude": 45.000,
            "longitude": -75.0000
        },
        "nav_options": {
            "nav_mode": "fastest",
            "avoid_highways": false,
            "avoid_tolls": false,
            "transport_mode": "car"
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Indeed that code does work perfectly. My problem is opening the map at a specific set of coordinates. I want to pass it a single location and it should open native BB maps at that location. I have also found that invoke.mapargs is not needed. :) Thanks for your reply. I appreciate it. And sorry if my question is a bit unclear, my mind is only halfway functioning at the moment.